# Trying to get PHP checkboxes to hold data from a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

Ive got to make a web-based checkout for an assignment and have come across a problem, ive imported a database and set up the data in a table with added check boxes alongside it. I need to take the reference number (stored first in the array) onto another page using sessions. From using var_dump i cant seem to get anything from the selected from the table.
Code:

Button code

```
<p><tr>
<input type="submit" name="Select" id="Select" value="Add Selected To Cart"/>  
</tr></p>
```

Access database code(values changed for saftey)

```
<?php
Accesses database
$con=pg_connect("host=hostname port=portnumbers
    dbname=name user=user password=password");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect to database');
    }
?>
```

Database display

```
//Creates table
echo "<table border='1'>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Title</th>
<th>Platform</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Buy</th>\n";

while($row = pg_fetch_array($res)){
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="' . $row['0'] .  '" /></td>';      
  echo"</tr>";    
  }

echo"</table>";
?>
```

Comment: is the html markup generated correctly?

Comment: it all displays correctly on the page, i just cant get any output from the selected array

Comment: but you did not post the code where you invoke the `var_dump`. Everythings looks fine above

Comment: Can you please show us the sql and php call you are using? Are you getting a result?

Comment: i was putting var_dump($selected) under the </table> and getting NULL

Comment: sorry i dont understand quite what you mean @Revent

Comment: Noup, should be `var_dump($_POST['selected']);` or `var_dump($_REQUEST['selected']);`

Comment: ok i was using the wrong code for that: result from that is "array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "18" [1]=> string(2) "20" }" with 18 and 20 being the numbers i need, all i cant do now is set them up as session variables to be able to re-call their rows data in a checkout in another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you can as follow because you are trying to improve a shopping car:

```
//Use the `$_SESSION` var to hold the values
foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $item)
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = $item;
```

As the item's id will be indexed, each time a submit is performed:

- If the item exists, will be replaced
- If the item does not exist, will be added

In order to remove items, you should use a "view cart" page and then show the items:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)
    echo '<a href="delete-item?id=' . $item . '">' . $item . '</a>';
```

Comment: ah ok, that clears it up, re the update, where in the code would you recomend this be placed?

Comment: That is so subjetive, I use this pattern:  [selection form] -> [add to the cart] -> redirect -> [selection form]. Where `add to the cart` you do place the code to add.

Comment: ah ok that seems to make logical sense, cheers :D i just need to use this array to somehow re-assemble the data into some sort of cart haha :P

Comment: what do you mean? You want to store the values of `$_SESSION` in mysql?